# Finding The Periodicity of $f(x) = \sin(x/2)\cos(x/3)$

Tags: periodic-functions

I want to find the periodicity of the following function: 
$$f(x) = \sin(x/2)\cos(x/3).$$
I have calculated the periodicity of the above functions which is $\pi/6$. Is it correct? Can you please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: what is your approach ?

Comment: I know that the period of sin and cos is 2*pi . So the periods of sin x/2 and cos x/3 are 4*Pi and 6*Pi . So the period of sin x/2 cos x/3 is 6*Pi

Comment: how have you deduced $6\pi$ from $4\pi, 6\pi$